My compiled version of Vim keeps getting replaced by a system standard version
This is a weird problem, looks impossible to me.
I'm running WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04) on Windows 11. I want to use Vim and because of some plugins I need Vim compiled with Python support and it must be version 9+, while the system standard version appears to be 8.2.
Everything works fine the day I compile vim. I install it with checkinstall. It works, it shows version 9.1, compilation time that day. But the next day (after waking the computer up from hibernation or some later time during the day) I notice that the version of Vim has changed to 8.2 (compiled March 14 2024)!
It has happened to me for the fourth time already this week. I'm sure the version 8.2 was not even installed at the system. Yesterday I made sure with apt remove and dkpg -r that I uninstalled any vim that might have resided there (and recorded the output of all commands), then I proceeded to install my compiled version of 9.1. Today it is 8.2 once again.
Every time this happens, first, it fails to open a new instance of vim saying "/usr/local/bin/vim" doesn't exist. Trying again, it does open Vim, but it's the 8.2 version (located at "/usr/bin/vim").
I've checked and the folder "/usr/local/bin/" doesn't exist. So it seems that the system keeps deleting it for some reason. That would partially explain why my version of Vim disappeared but I still don't understand how the other version appears without me installing it.
I've tried both using and not using update-alternatives after the installation or creating a symbolic link /usr/bin/vim -> /usr/local/bin/vim.
-- EDIT
sudo apt list --installed shows
vim-common/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.16 all [installed,automatic]
vim-runtime/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.16 all [installed,automatic]
vim-tiny/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.16 amd64 [installed,automatic]
vim/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.16 amd64 [installed]


I don't know what the cause of the problem was, but I've found a workaround. I've installed Vim from conda-forge. It seems to solve all my issues with Vim for now (especially the integration with conda environments).
